# Duvida Python com consulta em banco Firebird

Tags: python, python-3.x, query, firebird

Ola estou com um problema na consulta com o banco de dados firebird.
Faço a conexão com o banco e passo esta consulta, mas o problema esta no retorno, ele retorna o nome do produto normal só que o retorno do preco_venda vem com o "tipo decimal" descrito na frente do dado, mas sendo que o tipo do dado que esta cadastrado no banco é numeric.

```
cursor = conector.cursor()
cursor.execute("select e.descricao, e.preco_venda from estoque e where  '7853849020424' = e.barras")
lista = cursor.fetchall()

print(lista)

cursor.close()
conector.close()
```

[image: A primeira linha é o retorno da consulta a segunda e o tipo de dado cadastrado no banco]

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Esse `Decimal` não é tipo [`Decimal` do Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-fixedtypes.html#fblangref25-datatypes-decimal) esse é [tipo `Decimal` do Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html)

O módulo decimal foi projetado para suportar aritmética decimal não arredondada exata(aritmética de ponto fixo) e aritmética arredondada de ponto flutuante.

Para iniciar o uso do tipo decimal primeiro deve-se ajustar seu [Contexto de operação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#context-objects).

Contextos são ambientes para operações aritméticas. Eles governam a precisão, estabelecem regras para arredondamento, determinam quais sinais são tratados como exceções e limitam o alcance dos expoentes.

O método [`decimal.getcontext()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.getcontext) retorna o Contexto para o thread ativo.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext()
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])
```

Esse Contexto retornado é o [contexto na falta](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext). Seus valores são `prec= 28`, `rounding= ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, e traps para `Overflow`, `InvalidOperation`, e `DivisionByZero`.

Para ajustar uma das propriedades do contexto:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 7
```

Para definir um novo contexto use o método [`decimal.setcontext()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.setcontext) e passe como argumento um dos Contextos predefinidos [`decimal.Defaultcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext), [`decimal.BasicContext`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.BasicContext) e [`decimal.ExtendedContext`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.ExtendedContext), ou crie seu próprio contexto com o construtor [`decimal.Context()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context).

Instâncias decimais podem ser construídas a partir de números inteiros, strings, ponto flutuantes ou tuplas:

```
>>> Decimal(3) / Decimal(4)
Decimal('0.75')
>>> data = list(map(Decimal, '1.34 1.87 3.45 2.35 1.00 0.03 9.25'.split()))
>>> max(data)
Decimal('9.25')
>>> min(data)
Decimal('0.03')
>>> sorted(data)
[Decimal('0.03'), Decimal('1.00'), Decimal('1.34'), Decimal('1.87'),
 Decimal('2.35'), Decimal('3.45'), Decimal('9.25')]
>>> sum(data)
Decimal('19.29')
>>> a,b,c = data[:3]
>>> str(a)
'1.34'
>>> float(a)
1.34
>>> round(a, 1)
Decimal('1.3')
>>> int(a)
1
>>> a * 5
Decimal('6.70')
>>> a * b
Decimal('2.5058')
>>> c % a
Decimal('0.77')
```

As operações entre decimais são fechadas entre si.

Se quiser a representação textual de um decimal o converta para string:

```
>>> str(Decimal(1) / Decimal(7))
'0.1428571'
>>> f'{Decimal(Decimal(2) * Decimal("0.34")):g}'
'0.68'
```

Ou no seu caso:

```
cursor = conector.cursor()    
cursor.execute("select e.descricao, e.preco_venda from estoque e where  '7853849020424' = e.barras")
for row in cur.fetchall():
  print(f'Item: {row[0]}, Valor: {row[1]:g}')

cursor.close()
conector.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui "contornar" ou exibir as informações assim:

```
        cursor.execute("select e.descricao, e.preco_venda from estoque e where  '"+barras+"' = e.barras")
        retorno = cursor.fetchall()
           
        print(retorno[0][0])
        print(retorno[0][1],"RS")
```

Pois as informações estavam em uma tupla, desta maneira consegui exibir o conteúdo da posição.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]